# How to find the size of tensorflow dataset object?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have created tensorflow dataset object and I would like to know the size of this dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly `tf.data.Dataset` doesn't have a fully defined length.

One workaround approach would be to iterate over it once to get the number of elements

```
def get_ds_length(dataset):
    len = 0
    for _ in dataset:
        len += 1
    return len
```

Obviously this would be slow for large datasets and ones that use heavy preprocessing.

Comment: Yeah I had tried the above workaround and it is very slow